# Nested ng-repeats, filter and infinite scroll

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-scroll, angularjs-filter

I have a bit complicated data. We have leagues in the countries and events in the leagues. When rendering all data with nested ng-repeats, it means a serious reduction in performance. So we want to render data with infinite scroll. Also, I want to filter events by day of the week. If all the events in league filtered, league will be hidden. If all the leagues in region hidden, region will be hidden. 
How can I use this filtering structure with infinite scroll. What is the best solution?

Comment: I think you're asking too much here (infinite scroll, filtering/faceting, nesting). Please try to split your question, otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I'm asking how can i use these things together. But it seems hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest paginating your data instead of displaying all the data.
Furthermore, filtering should be an ajax call to the server which in his turn respond with the filtered data.

Comment: You're right. The most logical solution seems to filter through ajax.